# How to convert php array variable to javascript variable

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

Here is my code which is retrieving from db...
and i stored that column values in array() variable...

```
$res1 = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $res1[$i] = $row['address'];
    $i = $i + 1;
}

print_r($res1);
```

But problem is wen am trying to print this array it is printing as below:

```
"Array ( [0] => ameerpet [1] => panjagutta )"
```

but i need to print that array as below so that i can store in js variable for further using......

```
["ameerpet", "panjagutta"];
```

Comment: json_encode will help you.

Comment: Search function!! Usage is **not optional**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) to encode your array to JSON format:

```
$json = json_encode($res1);
```

You can use that variable in JavaScript and use then use `JSON.parse()`:

```
json = <?php echo $json; ?>
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
// obj now contains the array
```

Documentation: [**`JSON.parse()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON)

Comment: it is working but no need of json.parse....because if i use json.parse it is not accepting but wen i use direct var obj=<?php echo $json;?> it is accepting...

Answer (score 0):

Add this line where you want to declare the js array variable.

```
echo "var js_array = ". json_encode($res1) . ";\n";
```